# Visual Studio: Continue solution build on error in a post-build event

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to continue a solution build process on error?

My problem is this: robocopy returns code 3 ("(2+1) Some files were copied. Additional files were present. No failure was encountered.") in one of my projects. Even though the code is not problematic, this stops the build process. Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: set errorlevel = 0 resets the error state.  Do favor xcopy.exe

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much. If you can make this an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Why do you recommend xcopy over robocopy?

Comment: It has less bells and whistles that can cause undiagnosable failure.  Forcing the error to 0 isn't a great idea, harder to find out what went wrong when the error is one you shouldn't ignore.  Just complete the Q+A you started with your own post that describes what you discovered today and mark it as the answer.